# jQuery Drag and Drop inbetween two li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am developing a Tree view and using JQuery Draggable and Droppable plugins to implement Drag and Drop the tree nodes.

[image]

I can drag a folder and drop over another and get the dropped element in "drop" event handler. In my drop event handler I will rearrange my nodes.

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="dragul">
    <li class="dragli" id="1"><a class="draga">Folder1</a>
        <ul class="dragul">
            <li class="dragli" id="11"><a class="draga">Folder11</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dragli" id="2"><a class="draga">Folder2</a> </li>
    <li class="dragli" id="3"><a class="draga">Folder3</a> </li>
    <li class="dragli" id="4"><a class="draga">Folder4</a> </li>
    <li class="dragli" id="5"><a class="draga">Folder5</a> </li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
$( ".draga" ).draggable({
    cursor: "pointer",
    cursorAt: { top: 12, left: 18 },
    helper: function( event ) {
        var temp_name = event.target.innerHTML;
        return $( "<div id='draghelper' class='ui-widget-header drag-helper'>"+temp_name+"</div>" );
    }
});

$( ".draga" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // On dropping on a node will handle here to rearrange the node.
    },
});
```

Now I also need to drag a node and drop in between two nodes. Like need to drag "Folder5" and drop in between "Folder2" and "Folder3".

I also need to show a helper to drop in between two nodes when the dragged hover is in between the nodes.

JSBIN - [Link](http://jsbin.com/favija/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718721/jquery-tree-with-drag-and-drop with really great demo http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-dnd.html

Comment: @FrEaKmAn Thanks for your reply. Your reference points to other third party packages. In my product we need to achieve this using jQuery DND plugins, and not other third party plugins. I need suggestion to achieve using only jQuery DND Plugins.